# How to change the python version in a .net project?

Tags: python, .net-core, python.net

I need to use Tensorflow.net and Keras.net nuget packages for my project, but I have an error.

`Unable to load DLL 'python38' or one of its dependencies.`

I managed to remove this error by adding the python38.dll file to the bin folder. But I would like to use python 3.6 rather than version 3.8.

How can I set the version of python in my .net core project ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by lowering the version of Keras.net and taking a version 3.6.XX.

Comment: What if I have Python3.9 and Keras it supports 3.8?